# Vertex AI GoogleAuthError in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-api-nodejs-client, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a web server with one endpoint deployed on Heroku. Server purpose is to interact with Vertex AI gemini-pro LLM. Localy everything wors perfect because I am using a gCloud CLI auth but I want to implement a service account auth.

Here is the code sample of model init:

```
import { VertexAI } from "@google-cloud/vertexai";
import { GoogleAuth } from "google-auth-library";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const gAuth = new GoogleAuth({
  credentials: {
    client_email: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
    private_key: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
  },
});

const authClient = await gAuth.getClient();

const vertex_ai = new VertexAI({
  project: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  location: process.env.LOCATION,
  googleAuth: authClient,
});

const model = "gemini-pro";
const generativeModel = vertex_ai.preview.getGenerativeModel({
  model: model,
  generation_config: {
    max_output_tokens: 8192,
    temperature: 0.8,
    top_p: 0.8,
    top_k: 5,
  },
});

export default generativeModel;
```

I checked the service acc role - it's "Editor" so the problem is in model init.
Every time when trying to reach and endpoint I get the error:

```
2024-02-05T21:13:23.977555+00:00 app[web.1]: GoogleAuthError: 
2024-02-05T21:13:23.977557+00:00 app[web.1]: Unable to authenticate your request        
2024-02-05T21:13:23.977576+00:00 app[web.1]: Depending on your run time environment, you can get authentication by        
2024-02-05T21:13:23.977576+00:00 app[web.1]: - if in local instance or cloud shell: `!gcloud auth login`        
2024-02-05T21:13:23.977576+00:00 app[web.1]: - if in Colab:        
2024-02-05T21:13:23.977577+00:00 app[web.1]:     -`from google.colab import auth`        
2024-02-05T21:13:23.977577+00:00 app[web.1]:     -`auth.authenticate_user()`        
2024-02-05T21:13:23.977578+00:00 app[web.1]: - if in service account or other: please follow guidance in https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication
2024-02-05T21:13:23.977579+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
```

UPD: I found the solution in migrating to using API key:

```
import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(process.env.API_KEY);

const model = "gemini-pro";
const generativeModel = genAI.getGenerativeModel({
  model: model,
  generation_config: {
    max_output_tokens: 8192,
    temperature: 0.8,
    top_p: 0.8,
    top_k: 5,
  },
});

export default generativeModel;
```

Comment: Note that the `@google/generative-ai` version of the library doesn't use Vertex AI. It uses a different Google AI platform that has different licensing terms.

Comment: Thank you for your advices and help, I really appreciate it! I am thinking of getting back to Vertex AI in future but for now I needed a quick solution.

Comment: Should  I use Gemini through Vertex AI(@google-cloud/vertexai) or directly through Gemini (@google/generative-ai) ? What is the best option ?

Comment: @OmarSaade - This isn't really related to the original question.
The best option is the one that suits your needs. Both are similar to each other, but there are tradeoffs between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is an example of how you can utilize Gemini AI through Vertex AI. Note that the credentials can be obtained from your Google Cloud account via a .json file. After obtaining the credentials,
you can implement them in your app by placing them in the .env
file to ensure security.  This is a quick example of how you can use it.**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/vertexai

**Gemini Pro**(Streaming content generation,Streaming chat,Content generation: non-streaming)

**Gemini Pro Vision**(Providing a Google Cloud Storage image URI, Providing a base64 image string ,Multi-part content with text and video)

**Example:**

```
    const {
      VertexAI,
      HarmCategory,
      HarmBlockThreshold,
    } = require('@google-cloud/vertexai');
    
    
    
    const PROJECT_ID = '....';
    const LOCATION = 'us-central1';
    const GEMINI_PRO_MODEL_NAME = 'gemini-pro';
    const GEMINI_PRO_VISION_MODEL_NAME = 'gemini-pro-vision';
    
    const authOptions = {
      credentials: {
        client_email: '....',
        private_key: '.....',
      },
    };
    
    const vertexAiOptions = {
      project: PROJECT_ID,
      location: LOCATION,
      googleAuthOptions: authOptions,
    };
    const vertex_ai = new VertexAI(vertexAiOptions);
    
    const safetySettings = [
      {
        category: HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT,
        threshold: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE,
      },
    ];
    
    
    
    
    //             generativeModel  gemini pro
    
    
    
    
    const generativeModel = vertex_ai.preview.getGenerativeModel({
      model: GEMINI_PRO_MODEL_NAME,
      safety_settings: safetySettings,
      generation_config: {max_output_tokens: 256},
    });
    
    
    
    
     //          generativeVisionModel  gemini pro vision
    
    
    
    
    const generativeVisionModel = vertex_ai.preview.getGenerativeModel({
      model: GEMINI_PRO_VISION_MODEL_NAME,
    });
    
    
    
    // Content generation: non-streaming      : Gemini pro :
    
    
    
    async function nonStreaming() {
      const request = {
        contents: [{role: 'user', parts: [{text: 'who is james bond?'}]}],
      };
    
      try {
        const resp = await generativeModel.generateContent(request);
        const data = await resp.response;
        const textValue = data.candidates[0].content.parts[0].text;
        console.log('nonStreaming', textValue);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred during content generation:', error);
      }
    }

     nonStreaming();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues, I think, with how you're setting up the various authentication elements. Do you have a reference for where you were getting these attributes?

The biggest is that the `VertexAI` constructor doesn't have a `googleAuth` attribute in its initializing object which is of type [`VertexInit`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vertexai/blob/main/src/types/content.ts#L30). But it does have a `googleAuthOptions` attribute that is of type `GoogleAuthOptions`.

So I think your code should look something like

```js
const authOptions = {
  credentials: {
    client_email: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
    private_key: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
  }
}

const vertex_ai = new VertexAI({
  project: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  location: process.env.LOCATION,
  googleAuthOptions: authOptions,
});
```

It is also worth checking to make sure the various values that are coming from the environment are actually populated with the values you think they are.

Comment: Thank's for your help, but now I have more questions than answers :) 

I see that VertexInit looks loke this rn: 

```export declare interface VertexInit {
    project: string;
    location: string;
    apiEndpoint?: string;
}```

And also, what's that "preview" than? I don't get it :( 

```
export declare class VertexAI {
    preview: VertexAI_Internal;
    constructor(init: VertexInit);
}
```

Comment: And this preview class looks like: 

```
export declare class VertexAI_Internal {
    readonly project: string;
    readonly location: string;
    readonly apiEndpoint?: string | undefined;
    protected googleAuth: GoogleAuth;
    private tokenInternalPromise?;
    constructor(project: string, location: string, apiEndpoint?: string | undefined);
    get token(): Promise<any>;
    getGenerativeModel(modelParams: ModelParams): GenerativeModel;
}
```

Comment: @Roman - Welcome to StackOverflow! Giving more details in the comments is very difficult to read, particularly if its code. If this is an update of the original question to provide more details - edit the question and then post a comment that you've done so. If the answer has mostly resolved the problem and you have new questions, you should accept the answer and post a new question with as many details as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @Prisoner. Btw, I already found the solution in using API key.

Comment: Using an API Key uses the Google Generative AI / MakerSuite / Google AI Studio version of the API instead of the Vertex AI version.

Comment: Should  I use Gemini through Vertex AI or directly through Gemini ? What is the best option ?

Comment: The "best" option is the one that meets your needs. Currently, the AI Studio API has a rate limit, but is free, while Vertex AI does not have a rate limit, has a few additional features, but always incurs a cost. This is a matter of opinion and not a valid quesiton for StackOverflow.